# Does it matter if i use a Linq statement twice?

Tags: c#, linq

I wonder it matters when I use linq on an object more then once.
From a perfomance perspective should i store the result of First() in a variable or is it ok to call First() more often ?

```
internal class Program
{
    public record Item(string FirstName, string LastName, int Age);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item("John", "Doe", 33),    
            new Item("Some", "Guy", 59)
        };

        // A First
        Console.WriteLine($"{items.First().FirstName}, {items.First().LastName}, {items.First().Age}");

        // B 
        var item = items.First();
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.FirstName}, {item.LastName}, {item.Age}");
    
    }
}
```

First() is just an example it could be about Last() or Where()

Comment: Purely from a code maintenance view i'd prefer approach B

Comment: _"From a perfomance perspective should i store the result of First() in a variable or is it ok to call First() more often ?"_ I'd actually encourage you to find that out. You should use bigger data, though to see an effect. Also consider tools like benchmarkdotnet. Also take into account against what that LINQ is targeted: a local Collection, a Database (LINQ2SQL), EF Core ...

Comment: Are you always going to be iterating from a List, or from other sort of IEnumerable/IQueryable/Entity Framework?

Comment: Note: I think you'll find that `Console.WriteLine(item.FirstName, item.LastName, item.Age);` doesn't do what you think it does. In `Console.WriteLine(...);` overloads which accept multiple parameters, the first one is a format string and the rest are format arguments. You'll want to use `Console.WriteLine($"{item.FirstName} {item.LastName} {item.Age}");` or `Console.WriteLine("{} {} {}", item.FirstName, item.LastName, item.Age);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. It depends for example on ...

- if it's Linq-to-Objects or Linq-To-Entities (or Linq-To-Sql or whatever)

If it's not in memory, so not Linq-To-Objects you will execute the query again and again, so it is sent to the database multiple times. If it's already in memory it depends on ...

- is it a collection(like array or list) with an indexer or is it a "query"

If it's a "materialized" collection and also an `IList<T>` the indexer is used, so like `items[0]` which is basically a no-op. With other collections there might be more overhead, it must be enumerated to get the first or (worse)last.

If it's not "materialized"(search for 'deferred execution' in the docs like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-7.0)), so for examaple

```
var items = someHugeCollection.Where(somecondition);
```

and you now use `First` or `Last`, it must be executed again and again which might be expensive:

```
Console.WriteLine(items.First().FirstName, items.First().LastName, items.First().Age);
```

Then you should save either the collection in a variable(append `ToList` or `ToArray`) or the result `First` or `Last`(if you need both, store the collection in a variable).

So as a rule of thumb, **save it in a variable if you need it more than once**.

Answer (score 3):

In this synthetic code it won't matter much, but there's a more conceptual issue at play.

You usually use Linq methods when you want to address a collection through a database query (e.g. Entity Framework) or when you otherwise don't control the source collection and get passed an `IEnumerable<T>`. This means that you'll have to assume that enumerating/materializing is computationally expensive, and that multiple calls may involve multiple calls to databases/filesystems/generators/...

For all other intents and purposes, when you have an `IList<T>`, I'd say use the indexer `list[0]`, *and* save it in a separate variable for readability and maintainability.

Keeping a reference around to the first item also has another benefit: you won't necessarily know **whether the source collection is stable and/or modified by other threads or processes**. Here it is a local variable, but it may as well be an instance variable, or a list of files, or something that comes from a database that's being written to.

Meaning: the item returned by the first `First()` call may be different on successive calls.

A trivial example thereof:

```
var random = new Random();

IEnumerable<int> enumerable = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.OrderBy(_ => random.Next());

Console.WriteLine(enumerable.First());
Console.WriteLine(enumerable.First());
```

This does not necessarily write the same number to the console twice.

And purely about the performance aspect: as long as the C# compiler doesn't inline Linq's `First()`, `list[0]` is at least a couple of method calls and branches fewer than `list.First()`.

Comment: The multithreading aspect is really a good point. Didn't even think of it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. In say 95% of cases, the performance of the code really does not matter. So use whatever style you find most readable. Use profiling tools to check where your actual bottlenecks are and optimize where needed.

Note that`.First()` method is constant time, so it does not depend on the length of the list, at least assuming you are using it on a simple list. But many LINQ operations do depend on the length of the list, so if the lists are large you might want to be a bit careful.

If you are querying a database the runtime is often noticable, so you should ensure that the query is only run once, either by calling `.First()` and store the result, or use `.ToList()` to create an in memory representation of your data.

If you are processing really large amount of data and have high performance requirements, you typically want to avoid LINQ altogether. While LINQ is convenient, the abstractions it uses does impose some performance penalty.

Again, If you are unsure about the performance, use profiling tools to measure.